# Hibernate creates table for sequence defined in GenerationType.SEQUENCE

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have below code for Entity to generate sequence

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="hotel_seq") 
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name="hotel_seq",
        sequenceName="hotel_id_s"
    )
    private Integer id;
```

When I run the application, hibernate tries to creates a table with sequence and fails with below exception since I'm using Oracle Database and it doesnt support bigint data type.

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [create table hotel_id_s (next_val bigint)]
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Check you database dialect. It is probably not *Oracle*. Oracle doesn't have `bigint` datatype.

Comment: I have added below property to hibernate.properties file. dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect . And I still get same issue.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I have just replaced dialect with org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect from org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect. It worked after that , thanks for the help!!